# How to create a system with a dynamic modules?

Tags: django

I need to create a django system, but the client just have access in modules that it buyed. The system will be a 5 differents modules and i have to create to dynamic way.

How can i do that?

I have no ideia how can start a project like this.

Comment: Unfortunately this is too vague of a question and nobody on Stackoverflow will be able to answer it.
I recommend breaking down the question into smaller concise chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to have a look on django permissions:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization